# ObjectPersister configuration in FOSElasticaBundle

Tags: php, symfony, foselasticabundle

For my project I need a simple API for inserting documents into ElasticSearch. `FOS\ElasticaBundle\Persister\ObjectPersister` seems to be the right thing for me, but I see that the service defined with this class is abstract:

```
<service id="fos_elastica.object_persister" class="FOS\ElasticaBundle\Persister\ObjectPersister" abstract="true">
            <argument /> <!-- index -->
            <argument /> <!-- model to elastica transformer -->
            <argument /> <!-- model -->
            <argument /> <!-- properties mapping -->
            <argument /> <!-- options -->
</service>
```

How can I configure it to be able to inject into my services? Perhaps I should change smth in `fos_elastica.yaml`, which now looks like this:

```
fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default:
            url: '%env(ELASTICSEARCH_URL)%'
    indexes:
        categories: ~
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your fos_elastica config with:

```
fos_elastica:
    default_manager: mongodb
    clients:
        default:
            url: '%env(ELASTICSEARCH_URL)%'
    indexes:
        app:
            types:
                categories:
                    persistence:
                        # the driver can be orm, mongodb or phpcr
                        driver: mongodb
                        model: App\Document\Category #or whatever it is
                        provider: ~
                        finder: ~
```

You may need to modify your doctrine_mongodb configuration:

```
document_managers:
        default:
            auto_mapping: true
```

And you should be able to persist your Category entity with MongoDb object manager.

```
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentManager;

class YourService {

   private $documentManager;   

   public function  __construct(DocumentManager $documentManager){
       $this->documentManager= $documentManager;
   }

   public function yourService(){
       //use $this->documentManager
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for you response. My problem with this approach is that we don't have any other storage other than ES (neither SQL, nor MongoDB) and from what I understand driver is required for `persistence` config block. Might there be some workaround for it? cause couldn't find one so far.

Comment: I have the same requirement